# Price formatting thousands/decimal signs

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

In the webshop we're building we're outputting the price like so:

```
{{ cart.itemSubtotal|commerceCurrency(cart.paymentCurrency, convert=true) }}
```

which displays for example:

```
€1,680.00
```

We will be using multiple currencies in the webshop. Is it possible to set the thousands/decimals signs? Or does the CMS take these settings from the locale? We can't find the settings for this anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thousands/decimals signs are based on the current users locale and can not be configure at the moment. The number is formatted based on the currency and locale. You would need to make your own currency formatter as a twig extension.

You could set `format=false` in the craftCommerce filter, then pass the value to your own number formatter filter.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this feature will be added in the future?